# Pyro CMS -- No input file specified

Tags: php, pyrocms

I realize this isn't the place to post this, but i've searched and searched and asked on the forum of Pyro CMS with no response. Quite irritated about it already just want a solution!!!

I uploaded the Pyro CMS up to my server with GoDaddy it's a Linux

It then prompted me to start the installer, I click on Step #1 and see an error that says: `No input file specified.`

What do I need to do to fix this problem? It's very irritating and apparently the Pyro CMS team isn't willing to help.

Here is what I see after clicking `Step 1` on the first page of the installer!

[image]

Comment: What is displaying the error? Is it a PHP error? Can you post a screenshot or any more information?

Comment: I will post a screenshot! The console doesn't display any errors either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`

To your .htaccess file. If you don't have one, create it.

Comment: Do I just creat a .htaccess file and then copy and past that into it?

Comment: Also where do I place the .htaccess file?

Comment: Place it in the web root, where index.php is.

Comment: Now I get another Not Found error, I took a screenshot, here is a link to it: http://i1309.photobucket.com/albums/s627/mievan123/ScreenShot2013-08-01at104418PM_zpsb4efd5c6.png

Comment: Which folder is the .htaccess file in on the web server? You'll need to put that .htaccess file next to whichever index.php you're trying to use to install with. I realize this may sound confusing... feel free to instant message me if you would like some better help, my information is in my profile

Comment: Give me a link where you want me to message you.

Comment: I moved the .htaccess, and updated the permissions, and I'm still getting another error: `PyroCMS is missing system/cms/config/database.php and cannot find the installer folder. Does your server have permission to access these files?`

Comment: Do those files exists? What are the current permissions on them? Try changing them to 775 and seeing if that works.

Comment: Yes the files are in the locations and I have tried 775 as well as 777